# Stored Proceedure or GridView DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I've built a frontend to update an individual column for selected records in a GridView.  I've gotten that all setup the way that I want it to work including performing a check to be sure that more than one row is selected  (via a template field checkbox I added to the GridView) and that a column has been selected from a dropdown list.
[image]

I have everything down to the block of code that has to be built to do the actual update of the column for the selected rows.  This will cycle through each row, so if I've selected 5 rows it would trigger this code 5 times and update the record ID associated with that row.

I'm mainly debating with myself which would be the simplest to build into this. I at first thought about doing a stored procedure on the SQL Server and feeding it the record ID, column to update, and the value to write in the update. But then I got to thinking about it and realized that I have a GridView with a Data Source that was already setup to update the record as long as I called it

In either case I'll need to refresh the GridView after the update has been completed.

Just wondering what others might think would be the cleanest approach to this and just what my options might be. I've never seen a multi row column edit implemented so figure someone may have a better idea than me on how to go about this.

Here is my code block for the update as it is right now...

```
protected void SaveColEditBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Read the column select drop down List into Local Varriables 
  String SelectedColumnItem = ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedItem.ToString();
  String SelectedColumnValue = ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString();

  List<int> EditRows = new List<int>();
  List<string> recordnumber = new List<string>();
  foreach (GridViewRow grv in ActVulListGV.Rows)
   {
    if (((CheckBox) grv.FindControl("TagRowChkBx")).Checked == true)
    {
        //get current row rowindex if  checkbox  in it is checked 
        EditRows.Add(grv.RowIndex);
        //get the record number (RecID)
        recordnumber.Add(grv.Cells[2].Text.ToString());
    }
  }

int[] ERows = EditRows.ToArray();

if (recordnumber.Count > 1)
  {
      if (ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TicketNumber")
      {
        // Save Ticket number //
      }
      else if (ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() == "TicketClosed")
      {
        // Save Ticket Closed Value //
      }
      else if (ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Notes")
      {
        // Save Notes //
      }
      else if(ColumnSelectDDL.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Exception_ID")
      {
        // Save Exception ID // 
      }
      EditColMsgLbl.Font.Bold = true;
      SelectedRowsMsgLbl.Font.Bold = true;

      ColEditPnlExt.Show();
      EditColLbl.Text = SelectedColumnItem;

      SelectedRowsLbl.Text = "";

      foreach (string record in recordnumber)
      {
        // Insert the call of the procedure here to update the database
      }
  }
  else
  {
    UserMessageLbl.Text = " *** Choose 2 or more rows to use column edit feature! ***";
    mpePopUp.Show();
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends. If you are updating all at once, by looping, use a Stored Procedure. However updating one by one with `EditIndex`, it is easier to use the source. However I would recommend using code behind and a SP to update a row, then you could use the same SP for updating a single or all rows (good tutorial here: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control)

Comment: @VDWWD I would like to close this now but I'd like also to give you credit for your response. Can you resubmit your response as an answer?  
I've opted to go with a SP which was my first inclination to begin with but as I mentioned the thought that I had a DS ready to go kinda had me wondering if that was the most expedient choice.  Thank you for your input and the url.

Comment: Hi Ken. I've adden an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you are updating all at once, by looping, use a Stored Procedure. However updating one by one with EditIndex, it is easier to use the source. However I would recommend using code behind and a SP to update a row, then you could use the same SP for updating a single or all rows.

See [this excellent tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

And a tip if you have some time to spare in the near future, try to disable ViewState for the GridView. It will save a lot of tranfer kb's and overhead. But get the above to work first ;)